# Next13, different fetching results on server and client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've started a project using Next13. Everything went fine untill now. I'm beginner and I'd like to discover why I'm getting different results from fetching. As you may know - although the component is set to client, it renders on server as well and both of these two renders should match each other.
There is the fetching function:

```
export type CountryType = {
    name: string
    population: number
    region: string | undefined
    flagUrl: string | undefined
    capital: string | undefined
}

export default async function fetchData() {
    return fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((countries) => {
            return countries.map((element: any): CountryType => {
                return {
                    name: element.name.common,
                    population: element.population,
                    region: element.region,
                    flagUrl: element.flags.png,
                    capital: element.capital && element.capital[0],
                }
            })
        })
}
```

And here is the component that actually runs the function to fetch data - it works perfectly when the directive 'use client' is lost, 'cause it doesn't have to do fetching once again on client side.

```
'use client'

import CountryInput from '@/ui/CountryInput'
import CountryItem from '@/ui/CountryItem'
import SelectRegion from '@/ui/SelectRegion'
import React, { use } from 'react'
import fetchData, { CountryType } from './fetchData'

export default function Page(): JSX.Element {
    const countries: CountryType[] = use(fetchData())

    console.log(countries[0])

    return (
        <>
            <div className='w-full min-w-[315px] h-fit flex flex-col gap-y-12 px-4 items-center md:flex-row md:justify-between md:gap-x-2 md:px-16'>
                <CountryInput />
                <SelectRegion />
            </div>
            <div className='w-full min-w-[360px] h-fit flex flex-col gap-y-8 px-14'>
                {countries.map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <CountryItem
                            key={element.name}
                            name={element.name}
                            population={element.population}
                            region={element.region}
                            flagUrl={element.flagUrl}
                            capital={element.capital}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

As you may have noticed, there is a console log in this component - now I'm going to present to you what it returns on both client and server:

Server (in cmd):

```
{
  name: 'Iceland',
  population: 366425,
  region: 'Europe',
  flagUrl: 'https://flagcdn.com/w320/is.png',
  capital: 'Reykjavik'
}
```

Client (browser's console):

```
{
    "name": "Turkey",
    "population": 84339067,
    "region": "Asia",
    "flagUrl": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/tr.png",
    "capital": "Ankara"
}
```

The fact that these two things don't match each other causes the error generating endlessly:

```
Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
```

The longer page with this error runs, the more errors are generated.

I've searched on the Internet for the solution, I haven't found anything that could help me.

I've checked how this behaves on different browsers, different approches.
I expect these two console logs to be the same.

Comment: I found the solution, just use Edge. I don't know but Chrome works some strange way and it damaged the data.

Comment: I have no issue with this in Chrome / Firefox. It's just with how you are using client components to call the API. Check out my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not related to a browser. According to [Data Fetching: use in Client Components](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#use-in-client-components) you should not use `use` with `fetch` or it will cause re-renders and unwanted results.

The problem is this attempted async call in your client component:

`const countries: CountryType[] = use(fetchData())`

If you want React to load the async call when the component mounts, you can simply use a `useEffect(() => [])` to run an async call on mount.

They also recommend using a third-party library such as [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) or [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4).

I used your code in a barebones Next.js 13 app to demonstrate that both `client` and `server` components show the same first country using the same end-point.

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-js-13-test-server-client-api-calls-rphh17) that uses your code modified to demonstrate this.

For example inside of a **Next.js 13** app:

**page.tsx**

```
import ClientFetch from "./ClientFetch";
import ServerFetch from "./ServerFetch";

const App = async () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ClientFetch />
      <ServerFetch />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**ServerFetch.tsx**

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}

const ServerFetch: any = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  const countries = data.map((c: any) => {
    return {
      name: c.name.common,
      population: c.population,
      region: c.region,
      flagUrl: c.flags.png,
      capital: c.capital && c.capital[0],
    };
  });

  console.log("--- ServerFetch ---", countries[0]);

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>SERVER FETCH</h1>
      {[countries[0]].map((c: any, key: number) => (
        <div key={key}>
          <h3>{c.name}</h3>
          <p>{c.population}</p>
          <p>{c.region}</p>
          <p>{c.flagUrl}</p>
          <p>{c.capital}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

export default ServerFetch;
```

**ClientFetch.tsx**

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// export default async function
const ClientFetch = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
        const data = await res.json();
        setCountries(
          data.map((c: any) => {
            return {
              name: c.name.common,
              population: c.population,
              region: c.region,
              flagUrl: c.flags.png,
              capital: c.capital && c.capital[0],
            };
          })
        );
        console.log("--- ClientFetch ---", data[0]);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>CLIENT FETCH</h1>
      {countries.length
        ? [countries[0]].map((c: any, key: number) => (
            <div key={key}>
              <h3>{c.name}</h3>
              <p>{c.population}</p>
              <p>{c.region}</p>
              <p>{c.flagUrl}</p>
              <p>{c.capital}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </main>
  );
};

export default ClientFetch;
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: I haven't noticed this annotation, I had been focused on fixing the problem and I was reading only things that counted for me. A good lesson for me for the future. Actually, after changing the browser, problem is gone, after building the app everything works perfectly. Thank you so much for you help. I'm gonna keep this all in my mind.